# pypi - Server response (503): backend read error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypi

When I try to register a library in pypi with this command :

```
python setup.py register
```

I get this error :

```
running register
running check
Registering simplite to https://pypi.python.org/pypi

Server response (503): backend read error
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you manually register a package on PyPi?

Comment: 503 error suggests that it is either a bug ([report it](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi/issues)) or a temporary problem with pypy infrastructure (retry after a delay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same thing happen to me. This is just a temporary error. I tried again after a few minutes and it worked.